# Debugger for Python C++ combo for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger

In Visual Studio Code, is there a debugger that works with both Python and C++ codes where the former calls the latter? I have been using the "Python C++ Debugger" until it stopped working about a week ago after an VS Code update. Are there alternatives?

Comment: "_until it stopped working about a week ago after an VS Code update_" link to issue ticket please?

Comment: @starball: By "issue ticket" do you mean an error message?

Comment: oh I just assumed that you knew of a GitHub issue ticket about that change.

Comment: @starball: Here is the website of the debugger https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjamin-simmonds.pythoncpp-debug. It does not seem to have a GitHub account.

Comment: @Hans Hi Hans, I think you may need to report the issue here: https://github.com/benibenj/vscode-pythonCpp/issues It is the project page of the extension you mentioned. :)

Comment: @Hans You can choose to roll back the version of VSCode, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the previous VSCode version works and only the latest version encountered this issue, why not roll back to the old version?

Please go to this website:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80

I don't know the specific OS type on your side, but if it is windows, follow the below:

[image]

You can download whatever version of VSCode you want.

By the way, for the report place of the extension you mentioned, you can go to this place:

https://github.com/benibenj/vscode-pythonCpp/issues

Comment: Really appreciate for the information, especially the GitHub site. Let me look into it.